# How to get Matlab to read correct amount of xml nodes

Tags: matlab, xml-parsing

I'm reading a simple xml file using matlab's xmlread internal function.

```xml
<root>
    <ref>
        <requestor>John Doe</requestor>
        <project>X</project>
    </ref>
</root>
```

But when I call getChildren() of the `ref` element, it's telling me that it has **5** children.

**It works fine IF** I put all the XML in **ONE line**. Matlab tells me that `ref` element has **2** children.

It doesn't seem to like the spaces between elements.

Even if I run *Canonicalize* in oXygen XML editor, I still get the same results. Because Canonicalize still leaves spaces.

Matlab uses java and xerces for xml stuff.

## Question:

What can I do so that I can keep my xml file in human readable format (not all in one line) but still have matlab correctly parse it?

## Code Update:

```
filename='example01.xml';
docNode = xmlread(filename);
rootNode = docNode.getDocumentElement;
entries = rootNode.getChildNodes;
nEnt = entries.getLength
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code you are using to traverse the xml?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The XML parser behind the scenes is creating #text nodes for all whitespace between the node elements.  Whereever there is a newline or indentation it will create a #text node with the newline and following indentation spaces in the data portion of the node.  So in the xml example you provided when it is parsing the child nodes of the "ref" element it returns 5 nodes

1. Node 1: #text with newline and indentation spaces
2. Node 2: "requestor" node which in turn has a #text child with "John Doe" in the data    portion
3. Node 3: #text with newline and indentation spaces
4. Node 4: "project" node which in turn has a #text child with "X" in the data portion
5. Node 5: #text with newline and indentation spaces

This function removes all of these useless #text nodes for you.  Note that if you intentionally have an xml element composed of nothing but whitespace then this function will remove it but for the 99.99% of xml cases this should work just fine.

```
function removeIndentNodes( childNodes )

numNodes = childNodes.getLength;
remList = [];
for i = numNodes:-1:1
   theChild = childNodes.item(i-1);
   if (theChild.hasChildNodes)
      removeIndentNodes(theChild.getChildNodes);
   else
      if ( theChild.getNodeType == theChild.TEXT_NODE && ...
           ~isempty(char(theChild.getData()))         && ...
           all(isspace(char(theChild.getData()))))
         remList(end+1) = i-1; % java indexing
      end
   end
end
for i = 1:length(remList)
   childNodes.removeChild(childNodes.item(remList(i)));
end

end
```

Call it like this

```
tree = xmlread( xmlfile );
removeIndentNodes( tree.getChildNodes );
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this a common problem that everyone has? And do you know if it is a matlab one or Java one?

Comment: oops sorry ...I changed the name of the function right before I posted and forgot to change the recursive call to it in the function body...fixed now

Comment: Thanks! So is this a behavior of Java or Matlab do you know?

Comment: I just ran some code in java using the Xerces Dom parser located in javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder class and it had the exact same effect.  I am no xml guru, in fact my experience with it lies strictly within matlab, but I would guess that all parsers claiming to be DOM parsers will result in the exact same node structure.  Of course, their implementation will be different.

Comment: One other thing.  In matlab I never use xmlread.  I use a function called xml_read.m that I downloaded off of the File Exchange on mathworks.com. This is a great tool that converts xml directly to a struct in matlab. Sooooooo useful :)......[http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12907-xmliotools]

Comment: Dear cholland I tried to use your code to read my xml file it is working but I did not get anything as output. Do I miss something or I have to use these two code only

Answer (score 1):

I felt that @cholland answer was good, but I didn't like the extra xml work. So here is a solution to strip the whitespace from a copy of the xml file which is the root cause of the unwanted elements.

```
fid = fopen('tmpCopy.xml','wt');
str = regexprep(fileread(filename),'[\n\r]+',' ');
str = regexprep(str,'>[\s]*<','><');
fprintf(fid,'%s', str);
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: if you can improve on the regex, please do