# Matlab: urlread and textscan to retrieve html data

Tags: html, matlab, textscan, urlread

This is probably a basic question, but I'm new to MATLAB and have been struggling with it for a while. I'm trying to import data from a website using `urlread`. I can import the data into a cell but it is in html form and I lose all the table formatting. I thought I'd be able to retrieve it using `textscan`, but I end up with empty cells. The code I'm using is below. I've also tried saving the page and importing it using `uiimport`, with no luck.

```
data = urlread('http://www.extraskater.com/team/montreal-canadiens/2013/gamelog?sort=game');
readData = textscan(data, '%f %s %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f', 'delimiter');
```

Comment: What are you trying to import from that page?

Comment: I'm trying to get the numerical data in columns: TOI, GF, GA, CF, etc. I'd like to get them either as a matrix or individual vectors - either would work.

Comment: I think your best bet is to use a full [html parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20552447/2449192). Unfortunately, there isn't one built into MATLAB. Do you have to use MATLAB? Alternately, you could use something like Python to parse the HTML and print out a text file if you need to do some math in MATLAB (but Python can probably do that math as well)...

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I don't know much about Python, so I'll probably just copy and paste everything into Excel and import from there; I was just hoping Matlab had an easier way. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, sorry it didn't work out! Good luck!

Comment: Doing `urlread` will get the actual HTML source of the webpage.  Unfortunately, you won't be able to use `textscan` to get your data like that because the HTML page is not simply formatted like that.  There is a whole bunch of HTML code that is required to get it to look that way.  You could perhaps look into **regular expressions** to look for columns that have those column tags, but a HTML parser (like what @darthbith) recommends is the better approach.  Good luck!

Comment: That's a very helpful explanation, thank you!